# How to mathematically express the fact that the conditional probability $P(Y|X)$ can be independent of $P(X)$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Mathematically, $P(Y|X) = \frac{P(X,Y)}{P(X)}$ and so $P(Y|X)$ must depend on $P(X)$. Since $P(Y|X)$ will change when $P(X)$ changes.

However, consider this scenario:

- X = amount of red meat consumed per week.
- Y = probability of colon cancer.

Clearly, the probability of colon cancer given the amount of red meat consumed per week, $P(Y|X)$, does not depend on the distribution of red meat consumption in the population, $P(X)$.

The way I interpreted this situation is by treating $P(Y|X)$ and $P(X)$ as "independent variables" that can vary on their own. While $P(X,Y)$ is a "dependent variable" that cannot vary on its own and is purely calculated from $P(Y|X)$ and $P(X)$.

However, this feels like something I made up instead of a formal mathematical justification. Is there a canonical way of expressing this scenario in terms of mathematical probability?

Comment: You can easily construct examples where any two of $P(X),P(Y \mid X), P(X,Y)$ vary and the third does not change (rather like pressure, volume and temperature) so I have difficulty understanding the question

Comment: The question is unclear: $P(X)$ is a random variable as a transform of the rv $X$, and the same for $P(Y|X)$, hence one can consider whether or not the two rv's are independent. However, it seems that the OP considers the densities $p(y|x)$ and $p(x)$ for which "independence" has no specific meaning.

Answer (score 3):

1. $P(Y|X)$ won't change when $P(X)$ changes because $X$ is fixed in $ P(Y|X)$.
2. Mathematically, $P(Y,X)=P(Y|X)P(X)$, so if you change $P(X)$, *both sides* change proportionately to the change in $P(X)$ and $P(Y|X)$ is unchanged.